# Ajax PHP Jquery AutoSearch Code Fetching Data from Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery(function() {
    var autosuggestions = [
        "Airport",
        "Restaurant",
        "Shop",
        "Entertainment",
        "Realestate",
        "Sports",
        "Cars",
        "Education",
        "Garden",
        "Mechanic",
        "Offices",
        "Advertising",
        "Industry",
        "Postal",
        "Libraries"
    ];
    jQuery('#search-what').autocomplete({
        source: autosuggestions
    });
});
```

Please help me to write Ajax AutoSearch Code fetching data from Database and not using var autosuggestions.

Comment: explain your requirement briefly

Comment: Take a look here, it has many examples of autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Check the "Remote datasource" one.

Comment: In the above code, Data is fetched from pre-defined data using array var suggestions. But I want data should be drawn from database.

Comment: @TasosK.I have checked the above example. There, the data is shown in another div with div id log, But I want to show it in the same inputbox on autoselection.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the way that Google is doing search we call it search suggest or autocomplate.

there  are a lot of way to do this but if you are begginer or don't have time and finding  a good and fast way for this try [jquery UI autocomplate](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

That is so easy:

Your script:

```
     <script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

and HTML

```
  <div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

and after you working with this and if you know how to work with autocomplate then start to fetching data from database, there is a good tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537721/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-database) and [HERE](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/)

Comment: I am already using a script for autosearch, but need to add autosearch feature, fetching data from database in the above code that you have mentioned.

Comment: please visit http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537721/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-database

Comment: Please help, I am a beginner in this.. Need your support. What would be the server side code for this.

Comment: @AwdeshBhatti please first check this answer for the your selected answer